# Programmatically configuring S3 options in Flink

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Apparently Flink 1.14.0 doesn't correctly translate S3 options when they are set programmatically. I'm creating a local environment like this to connect to local MinIO instance:

```
  val flinkConf = new Configuration()
  flinkConf.setString("s3.endpoint", "http://127.0.0.1:9000")
  flinkConf.setString("s3.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider")

  val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI(flinkConf)
```

Then `StreamingFileSink` fails with a huge stack trace with most relevant messages being `Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAuthWithAWSException: No AWS Credentials provided by SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint:`  which means that Hadoop tried to enumerate all of the credential providers instead of using the one set in configuration. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

I've spent ages trying to figure out this one too. I could not find a way to set it programmatically, but adding the following to src/main/resources/core-site.xml in my Flink java project root worked in the end:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider</name>
        <value>com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Then I could use AWS_PROFILE env var to select stored credentials.
This was for Flink with flink-s3-fs-hadoop 1.13.2